# Errno 13-Permission denied: '/User'

Tags: django, python-2.7, imagefield

I got this error message when I trying to add a profile photo for a user in django admin(127.0.0.1:8000/admin)

Can anyone help me to figure out the reason ?

---

> OSError at /admin/role/role/6/
>   [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/User'
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/role/role/6/
>   Django Version: 1.8.2
>   Exception Type: OSError
>   Exception Value:
>   [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/User'
>   Exception Location: /Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7/os.py in makedirs, line 157
>   Python Executable:  /Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.7.10
>   Python Path:
>   ['/Users/wangjohnson/superpm',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python27.zip',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/Extras/lib/python',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>    '/Users/wangjohnson/Envs/TUAN/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

model.py

```
class Role(models.Model):
SEX_CHOICES = {
    ('MALE','MALE'),
('FEMALE','FEMALE'),
}
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
role = models.CharField(max_length=30)
sex = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=SEX_CHOICES)
intro = models.TextField()
age = models.IntegerField()
product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='roles')
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
```

def **unicode**(self):
        return self.name

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/User/wangjohnson/superpm/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

in MEDIA_ROOT = '/User/wangjohnson/superpm/media/'

'User' should be 'Users'

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs, if process (./manage.py runserver) started by user who doesn't have writing permission for media folder.
I solved that issue by starting screen and runserver process with root user.